# Handling of accents and umlauts when printing to Command Shell not working

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to print the page title from some source code using scrapy into Command Prompt/Line. This is causing errors if any of the characters are non standard (i.e. have accents, umlauts etc). I have tried using the following:

```
myheader = titles.extract()[0]
myheader = str(myheader)
print '********** Page Title:', myheader.decode('utf-8'), '**********'
```

and...

```
myheader = titles.extract()[0]
        myheader = str(myheader)
        print '********** Page Title:', myheader.decode(), '**********'
```

and...

```
myheader = titles.extract()[0]
        myheader = str(myheader)
        print '********** Page Title:', myheader.encode('utf-8'), '**********'
```

An example something I am trying to print that is causing this error is:

```
<meta name="title" content="Mustang Cup Liga Postobón Clausura tables, rankings & standings | WhoScored.com">
```

Which produces an error at position 23 within the text 'Mustang Cup Liga Postobón Clausura tables, rankings & standings | WhoScored.com"' as this is where the accent above the letter 'o' is.

The actual error is:

```
exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 23: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Can anyone suggest why none of my above methods are not working?

Thanks

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham hi again,  have amended the question to show the error. thanks

Comment: http://pyvideo.org/video/948/pragmatic-unicode-or-how-do-i-stop-the-pain

Comment: where are you running the code?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham in command shell

Comment: when you print myheader what happens?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i think i have fixed it now. i was trying to .encode something i had already converted to a string. when i took that line out it stopped causing errors.

Comment: yep, I thought that was what was happening

Answer (score 0):

1. `Selector.extract()` always returns lists of unicode.
2. Be careful with `str` it will encode with the default encoding (ascii).

So the correct way of doing it:

```python
myheader = titles.extract()[0]
print u'********** Page Title: {} **********'.format(myheader).encode('utf-8')
```